# CakePHP and XenForo

Tags: php, cakephp, path, forum

For my application I'm trying to implement the **XenForo** forum software into my **CakePHP** site. I've installed `XenForo` in `AppName/app/webroot/community` and the system itself works as intended. When going to `http://localhost/AppName/community` however, it redirects me to `http://localhost/AppName/app/webroot/community/`

Going to `http://localhost/AppName/community/` (note the trailing slash) gives me an unmarked up page of the forum with an Error that the page could not be found.

I would like to prevent this from happening, and make XenForo use the URL I've supplied. I've tried setting the `<base>` to `<base href="http://localhost/AppName/community/" />`, but to no success.

The Board URL in the Admin CP of XenForo is also set to `http://localhost/AppName/community` (with no trailing slash)

If you have a clue how to fix this, that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find an exact solution to my issue, but kind of moved around the issue by placing my community folder from `/app/webroot/` to the root `/`. In addition I had to add this line to the **.HTACCESS** file:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/community(.*)`

**Edit 11-23-2012:** I seem to have found the solution I was looking for. I moved my installation back to /app/webroot and set the DocumentRoot in my vhost file accordingly:

`DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/sitename/app/webroot`